# Power Query Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, export-to-excel

In excel I have three columns A, B, C. Each column has values from A2:A33, B2:B33, C2:C33. In this column A value is 55.jpg and column B value is 1 for all rows. The value in C is different . In this case I want to align the values in Row 2 to single row like C3 in D2....

Comment: Can you give a sample of the source data and/or the result you're looking for ?

Comment: Why did you include PowerQuery in your title?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "aligning values" in row 2? Can you give samples of data and what's expected from that?